# Does Excluding Internal Traffic Also Filter out Referral Traffic in GA

Tags: google-analytics, ip-address, metrics

We are excluding internal traffic from Google Analytics on our site. The question is, does it also exclude referral traffic if one of our team members, for example, visits our site from an external link?

Example:

Employee A Clicks on External Link --> Lands on our Site

Employe A has her IP address filtered out in Google Analytics. Does this count as a referral visit in GA?

Thanks for your valuable input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe it would as you are filtering by IP, and the IP does not change regardless of how you reached the site (referral, direct, organic, etc.).

Comment: Ok nice thanks, that's what I was thinking but I couldn't find anything online to verity this, if you happen to have any reference please post! Thanks.